# About Encapsulation : properties

Tags: c#, encapsulation, console.writeline

Case I :

```
class example
{
   private int roll;
   public int Roll
   {
       get { 
           return roll; 
       }
       set{
           if (value > 0)
           { roll = value; }   
       }
   }
   //public example()
   //{
   //    roll = 500;
   //}

}

class practice_4
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        example ABC = new example();
        Console.WriteLine(ABC.Roll = -1);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Output : -1

I have set a business logic that does not contain any illegal value and gives me by default value "0"..

Case II:

```
class example
{
   private byte roll;
   public byte Roll
   {
       get { 
           return roll; 
       }
       set{
           if (value > 0)
           { roll = value; }   
       }
   }
   //public example()
   //{
   //    roll = 500;
   //}

}

class practice_4
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        example ABC = new example();
        Console.WriteLine(ABC.Roll = -1);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Above code is displaying compile time error as I just change valuetype Int to byte

error: constant value -1 cannot converted to byte ...

what Console.WriteLine Method really do ?

Comment: It's not the `Console.WriteLine` that is doing anything special. You are misunderstanding what `ABC.Roll = -1` actually does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because assigment expression returns the value that is being assigned which is `-1` in this case. it doesn't return the `ABC.Roll`, you can verify that by outputting the property value after the assignment:

```
Console.WriteLine(ABC.Roll = -1); //-1
Console.WriteLine(ABC.Roll); //0
```

So the `ABC.Roll` actually never changes cause of the validation logic in `setter` method.

Answer (score 1):

An assignment has a return value (the assigned value). So even though you're not storing the `-1` it's still the return value of the assignment itself.

This would print `0`:

```
ABC.Roll = -1;
Console.WriteLine(ABC.Roll);
```

Comment: lol
i know that....
it will give me the output 0
as my business logics is value > 0 
and compiler have set by default 0 for int valuetypes

Comment: Your question is why it prints `-1` when you were expecting `0` in your example and I'm telling you why: Because you were writing the return value of the assignment instead of the property and I'm showing you the difference.